# Unable to make a GET request with React Native on physical device

Tags: node.js, react-native

My setup: The server is running locally on my machine, and I have the React Native app running on my physical phone. Here is the code snippet for the mobile app:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, StatusBar} from 'react-native'

import axios from 'axios'

export default function App() {
    const [dkc, setDkc] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://192.168.10.104:3333/dkc')
            .then(response => {
                setDkc(response.data); //Doesn't goes here
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(`Error: ${error.message}`); //Goes here [Network Error]
            ;
        }, []);
    });

    //Code for the app style

};
```

And here is the code snippet for the server:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors())

function preRequisicao(req, res, next){
    const {url, method} = req;
    console.log(`[${method.toUpperCase()}] ${url}`);
    return next();
}

app.get("/", preRequisicao, (req, res) => {
    return res.json({ message: "ok" });
});

app.get("/dkc", (req, res) => {
    return res.json({ character: ["donkey kong", "diddy kong", "dixie kong", "kiddy kong"]});
});

app.listen(3333, () => {
    console.log(" Port 3333")
});
```

I can make requests, for example, on Insomnia, it returns the data. What's the info that I'm missing here?

Comment: What's `api.get()`? Is it supposed to be `axios.get()`? Also, I believe you may run into problems trying to make requests to unsecure URLs from certain devices / operating systems. What device are you running this on?

Comment: Had to edit my question, meant to be `axios.get()`. And I'm using a LG K10

Comment: try an HTTPS, it might be that App Transport Security is blocking it

Comment: Did try that, unfortunaly it did not work

Answer (score -2):

Modify your code to this

```
app.get("/dkc", (req, res) => {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json') 
    return res.json({ character: ["donkey kong", "diddy kong", "dixie kong", "kiddy kong"]});
});
```

This code work as in this https://github.com/SoftCareTech/NumberToWords/blob/main/Node%20API/routes/v2.js
Api test uri   https://github.com/SoftCareTech/NumberToWords
Test using the above different server
Pls supply your error message for clarification

if you are running react native web CORS is required. If not you can remove it like this

```
app.get("/dkc", (req, res) => {  
    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json') 
        return res.json({ character: ["donkey kong", "diddy kong", "dixie kong", "kiddy kong"]});
    });
```

Comment: OP already had CORS configured (not that Its required for react-native). There's no way this actually solves the problem

Comment: Noted but if you are running react native web CORS is required.

Comment: Quick update, probably my NodeJS server was not updated when I was testing this that day, it did not apply the `app.use(cors())` code. Today it worked just fine, even without the request header you pointed out... Sorry for wasting everyone's time on this